# Step-up layout - Is important trace order?

Tags: circuit-design, layout, routing, step-up

I am adding step-up to my PCB and I wonder if I have to make trace order like [in this design](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=1e0ffd31e583452cb9b2fc5893aff53e%7Cf5993e72640343db8f215d259a995500). I mean if input voltage has to go first through power inductor, then capacitor and finally step-up converter IC.

My design is following: Input (SW2_1) shares trace with IC (U4) then capacitor (C8) and power inductor
 (L1)[image]

Schematic
[image]

EDIT: update layout (no silk)
[image]

Comment: Post the schematic for that in your question.

Comment: What chip are you using? Have you looked at the recommended layout for it?

Comment: Careful with GND vias on a chip pad - they tend to suck away solder. Commercial assembly plugs these vias before soldering, so the solder joint will be reliable.

Comment: @Neil_UK added to post

Comment: @RonBeyer I am using MT3608 like in the original link. Yes I tried, however datasheet doesnt have recommended layout :/

Comment: @rdtsc Ok thanks for tip, I will move them somewhere else.

Comment: Via in pad is not an issue if hand soldering with an iron. It can be if you are reflowing, especially if the pad is small and the via area is large.

Comment: @DKNguyen I mostly use hotair + tin paste

Comment: I'd say your layout looks fine.  Input going to a cap and then branching out is good EMC practice, but in this case it's so close I doubt it would matter.  I would switch C3 and R4 to prevent your current sawtooth from affecting the feedback value, though.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis ok thanks for tip, I will switch them and update post above with new ver, keeping old aswell

Comment: With a switcher like this, you've got to keep the loops where current changes as small as possible. Current through L1 diverts either into U4 or D5+C2. They are nearly as tight as you can physically make them, well done. Pushing D5 right up to C2 would improve things slightly, only very slightly, but you might as well do it. Power being applied right at C8 couldn't be any better than how you have it, but another ground via for C8 between the pads would be prudent. As you've moved C3, give both C2 and C3 a ground via each between the pads.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks! Updated edited layout. Would you approve this for production?

Comment: That fragment is looking good with another ground via for C8. Note sure why you've fattened up the L1 traces since the original draft, was that for heatsinking L1? There's no need to do it for series inductance!

Comment: @Neil_UK I thought to make GND dissapear based on jupiter.guo idea. However Reverted that change. Does updated layout now makes sense?

Comment: You're still resisting putting that extra ground via into space between C8 pads. Not sure what jupiter meant by ground under L1 cannot be existed. You'll need to look at the datasheet for the specific inductor you're using. I've had a quick look at a few 7x7 inductors but can't identify a 7x7x4 one out of the dozens there. The Wurth ones say 'no vias or sensitive traces under', so maybe there could be conductors under, and incomplete shielding of the field, so some types? Ground covered in resist should not be a problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK ok, added :) thanks

Comment: yeah, maybe jupiter.guos recommendation to remove the ground beneath the inductor is based on the assumption that a) the inductor is unshielded (might be, but most I've seen in that form factor are shielded), and b) that your ground is sensitive here (which it really isn't, this is a SMPS, the ground here by definition is subject to large switched currents, which happen to be synchronous with the magnetic field....

Answer (score 1):

1. The GND between L1 cannot be existed.
2. C3 should replaced with R4.
3. C3 GND should connected with MT3608 pin 2

May these help you.

Comment: thanks for tips, can you check updated layout? C3 replaced. Are vias properly positioned? Btw from bottom is ground (L1) is there any problem?

Comment: Why 1., jupiter.guo?